# Retrieve salary per component from Exact Online using Invantive SQL

Tags: exact-online

How can I retrieve the salary per individual component and employee using the ado.net provider of Invantive SQL for use within Microsoft Power BI?

I seem unable to find a XML or REST-based table that contains the amounts.

Comment: What field(s) are these values stored in?

Comment: @music2myear We can't know that since we don't have access to the internal database servers behind the Exact Online app. Salary components is a part of the Exact Online user interface though (under Employees > Components).

Comment: Then I would recommend contacting the Exact Online folks. They will know if that information is extractable and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to extract salary information on that level. The REST API has no support at all for salary components, and all Payroll endpoints are GET only, so you can't insert or update that data.

The XML Export functionality and the XML API have some support for salary components, but only on the general level above employees. There is no endpoint to get the data from salary components by employee.

That said, there seems to be no way to get the information you want at this time: not via de user interface (XML export) nor using the APIs.